# Problem installing cmake with MacPorts

Tags: cmake, macports

I'm using MacPorts to try to install cmake, and its giving me this. I've looked online for help on this, to no avail. Any ideas on how to get this to go away?

Running OSX 10.6.6 (2.4 Ghz i5, 4GB)

```
$ sudo port install cmake
--->  Computing dependencies for cmake
--->  Building cmake
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
Log for cmake is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_cmake/main.log
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
$
```

Comment: Yes... do "cat /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_cmake/main.log" and see what it says. If it was an rsync issue, just try again. Perhaps there was a Tasmanian devil tearing through a network cable at the very moment you were trying to pull the sources down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem on a MacBook Pro with Snow Leopard.
I read on [a Mac OS Forge thread about MacPorts](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/26934) that I should install the [Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 3 Developer Package](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wo/5.1.17.2.1.3.3.1.0.1.1.0.3.9.3.3.1) so I did just that, also re-installed xcode from the Snow Leopard installation DVD, then did:

```
$sudo port clean cmake
```

then tried installing cmake again and it worked!

I don't know what was the exact problem so if installing the Java Update Developer Package doesn't do the trick please try all of the above..